# Compile Error: Invalid Use of Property

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an Access DB that I am constructing. My VB education is bits and pieces I've needed to customize the DB more than what Access does so it's very spotty. I have a button that runs the following code when pushed. The code works fine. The issue is when I go to the VB screen and Compile under the Debug menu, I get an error stating "Compile Error: Invalid Use of Property."

```
' Memo Line Button Script
Private Sub Memo_Line_Click()
On Error GoTo Memo_Line_Click_Err

    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    Memo_Line ([Forms]![Logform]![HLCtrl]) 'error highlights ![HLCtrl]

Memo_Line_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Memo_Line_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Memo_Line_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Memo_Line refers to a public function. That code is listed below.

```
' Copy Offer Memo Line Data to Clipboard Button Script
Public Function Memo_Line(HLC)
On Error GoTo Memo_Line_Click_Err

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Log-Memo Line", acNormal, "", "[HL#]=" & "'" & HLC & "'", , acNormal
    Call ClipBoard_SetData([Forms]![Log-Memo Line]![Memo])
    MsgBox ([Form_Log-Memo Line].[Memo] & " --- copied to Clipboard."), vbInformation, "Clipboard Details"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Log-Memo Line"

Memo_Line_Click_Exit:
    Exit Function

Memo_Line_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Memo_Line_Click_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled by the statement "The code works fine.", followed by a description of how it won't compile because of an error. In the VBA editor, under `Tools > Options...` on the "General" tab do you have a checkmark beside "Compile On Demand"? That is the default, and it means that changes to the code will trigger a re-compile the next time it is run.

Comment: Yes, it is checked. I mean that when I actually click the button the code is attached to, the code works as expected. When I am editing the code in other parts of the DB and choose Debug, Compile, that is when I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discard the parentheses in your function call.

```vb
Memo_Line [Forms]![Logform]![HLCtrl]
```

If `Memo_Line` returned a value and you wanted to do something with that value, you would need the parentheses.

```vb
MyVariable = Memo_Line([Forms]![Logform]![HLCtrl])
Debug.Print Memo_Line([Forms]![Logform]![HLCtrl])
```

Actually, since `Memo_Line` doesn't return a value, you could make it a subroutine instead of a function.  I'm not suggesting you make that conversion, but call it using one of these styles if you do:

```vb
Memo_Line [Forms]![Logform]![HLCtrl]
Call Memo_Line([Forms]![Logform]![HLCtrl])
```

In the sample database, your form includes a command button named *"Memo Line"*.  In some situations, Access substitutes an underscore for the space, so *"Memo Line"* becomes *"Memo_Line"*.  The problem there is that you also have a function named *"Memo_Line"*.  Unfortunately Access thinks you're referring to the command button instead of the function in this code line:

```vb
Memo_Line ([Forms]![Logform]![HLCtrl]) 'error highlights ![HLCtrl]
```

The code compiled without error after I changed the command button name to *"cmdMemo_Line"*.

No doubt that name collision, which resulted from space vs. underscore, caught you by surprise.  I find it best to avoid spaces in control names as well as other object names: tables; fields; forms; etc.

Comment: Trying both options still gets me the error but now it highlights Memo_Line instead of ![HLCtrl]

Comment: I've already declared HLC as a public variable as a string. I used HLC in other functions.

Comment: Alright, I have uploaded it to Google Drive. I've erased all confidential data and replaced it with generics. I know the DB is a huge beast. What I want to know is about this specific issue for now. This is a work in progress. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1TwC_jW-zqUMHJxWUc2bnBJWXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why is it always the easy things that trip everyone up? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this one instead of Call function

Application.Run "Memo_Line"